# For loop identifying inexistent NAs in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, na

I have a big dataframe called z with 107310 rows and 8 columns. It has no NAs as it went through this function: `z<-z[complete.cases(z),]` to eliminate all rows containing NAs.

I created the following for loop to remove all rows if the value of a specific column where higher than that of another specific one.

Firstly, I tried the following code:

```
  for(row in 1:nrow(z)){
   i <- z[row, 1]
  j <- z[row, 2]
  ci<- z[row, 6]
  cj<- z[row, 7]
  year <- z[row, 8]
      if(cj>ci){
    z<-z[-row,]}
}
```

The loop would run through but stop at some row indicating the following error:

“ error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed "

Even though there where no NAs, I adapted the loop to avoid the error, making the values in the if statement always numeric:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(z)){
  i <- z[row, 1]
  j <- z[row, 2]
  ci<- z[row, 6]
  cj<- z[row, 7]
  year <- z[row, 8]
  temp<-ci-cj
  temp<-ifelse(!is.na(temp),temp,0)
  if(temp<=0){
    z<-z[-row,]}
}
```

However, the loop still stops before it eliminates all rows in which cj>ci. The last values it genereates for i and j is NA and for ci and cj are NA_real, even though those values are not NAs in the data set.

Does anyone know what is happening?
Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're not just doing `z[z[,6]>=z[,7],]`?

Comment: You define the number of rows to loop over when the frame is at its largest. If any rows are removed, eventually the loop will go to a row-number higher than what `z` currently contains. (`1:nrow(z)` is evaluated only once.) Perhaps you could use `row <- 1; while (row < nrow(z)) { ...; if (temp<=0) z <- z[-row,] else row <- row + 1; }`

Comment: Many thanks!! Yes, I definitely could have just  done what iod said, it worked perfectly. Also, thank yoy r2evans, for the explanation it makes a lot of sense. Sorry about the beginner's mistake.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could avoid for loops by using a 2-step process. First use `ifelse` to flag out the cases which are undesirable and then use `subset` to remove them like this:

```
z$flag <- ifelse(z$col6 < z$col7, 1, 0)
new_z <- subset(z, flag == 0)
```

this is assuming that the 6th and 7th columns are named 'col6' and 'col7'.

Comment: That's true. My question was not smart, I could indeed have avoid the for loops the way suggested or simply like this: z<-z[c(z[,6]>z[,7]),]. It  all worked. Nevertheless, I still don't know why the NAs were founded in the loop.Many thanks! 
.